# How to install AMD Crimson video drivers on iMac 5K (Late 2014) in Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, imac, windows, driver

I installed Windows 10 using Bootcamp on my iMac.

Bootcamp installed a bunch of drivers including one that allows proper 5K rendering on Windows.

However when I play a recent game Rainbow Six Siege, I see a ton of flickering of textures. The more I move around and shoot, the more they flick around.

Googling leads me to the solution of installing the new AMD Crimson driver's however, it seems I cannot install it on a Bootcamp Windows 10 version.

Is there a way around this?

---

My specs:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2015/09/21/update-amd-display-driver-under-bootcamp/

it worked out for me I have the same config as you and I had the same problems with Rainbow Six Siege 
good luck trying